# How should I choose an accepted answer if several are good?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, votes

I asked this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1069339/urgent-questions-about-dnschangers). I accepted one of the answers, but honestly both were great. Which one is better? Consider:

- Which was first.
- Which has more information.
- Which has more links.
- Which is more clear to future visitors.
- Which you think is better.

How would you choose which to mark as accepted when both are good?

Comment: If both answers are equal in all apsects then choose the first to post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have accepted [the answer you did](https://superuser.com/a/1069379/380318).

I really like that it quoted the different questions; that made it much easier to read. Speaking of different questions, asking so many different things in one post is frowned upon (and why your question was closed as *too broad*).

The accepted answer is to the point where appropriate (e.g. in response to #3) and more expanded when things are less cut and dry (e.g. #6). Paragraph breaks are inserted tastefully - again, helping with readability.

---

Now for some other matters. I suggest being more specific with your titles. *Never* say something is urgent here. If it's truly urgent, get professional assistance. Make the title say something of substance about the post; writing it as an interrogative sentence helps with that. Remember, the title and tags are the only thing people will see of your question in question lists.

It's nice to be polite and say thanks, but we don't include such things in post bodies here. Upvotes and the accept mark express gratitude; texts like "thanks in advance" don't add anything and are likely to be removed.

Finally, on meta, polls are usually conducted by just asking a question and waiting for answers. The only kind of meta posts where voting indicates agreement or disagreement have the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tag. Otherwise, positive votes indicate that the discussion is useful; negative votes indicate the opposite.